# Add disassembly comment at rip in radare2

Tags: debugging, radare2

When in visual mode (command `v`) in radare, in the disassembly panel, I can press <kbd>;</kbd> to add a comment at the location I am current seeked to (which is the top instruction in the disassembly view). I usually step through the software and would like to add comments at the current instruction pointer (`rip`) location.

Is there a key for that? Can I define one or redefine the <kbd>;</kbd> key?

Answer (score 1):

In visual mode open up the radare console with `:` and enter

```
CCa @rip your comment
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that this should be something like `.` followed by `;`. According the manual:

- `.` : Seek to program counter
- `;` : Add comment

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But then I have to seek back and I can't see the code while typing. I would prefer to add a comment at rip.